# C passing shared variables into pthreads

Tags: c, variables, pthreads

I wrote the following program to test some assumptions I have about pthreads:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h> 
#include <unistd.h>

typedef struct threadArgs * ThreadArgs;

void *foo( void * argStruct );

struct threadArgs{

    int pingBool;
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){

    pthread_t t1; 
    int pingBool = 1;
    int ch;
    ThreadArgs args = (ThreadArgs)malloc(sizeof(struct threadArgs));
    args->pingBool = pingBool;
    pthread_create(&t1, NULL, foo, args);

    while((ch = getchar()) != EOF ){

        if( ch == 'q' ){
            pingBool = 0;
            printf("pingBool now 0\n");
            break;
        }
    }

    pthread_join(t1, NULL);
    printf("whole program terminating\n");
    return 0;
}

void *foo( void * argStruct ){

    ThreadArgs args = argStruct;

    while( args->pingBool == 1 ){

        printf("t1 still going\n");
        sleep(1);
    }
    printf("t1 finished\n");
    return NULL;
}
```

Basically, it sets a variable `int pingBool = 1` in `main()`, passes it into a thread which loops until `pingBool == 0`. `main()` then sets `pingBool = 0`, however, the thread continues to run. I'm pretty sure this is happening because `pingBool` is getting copied when it is put into the struct and only the copy local to `main()` is being modified.

Is there a way to share and modify variables between threads like this? I am aware that I can simply make `pingBool` a global variable rather than pass it into `foo()`. However, I would prefer not to do that.

Note: If you want to test the code you need to compile with -pthread or -lpthread depending on your compiler. i.e. gcc -Wall -Werror -pthread -o test test.c

Comment: 1) the parameter `argc` is not used.  the compiler will raise a warning.  2) the parameter `argv[]` is not used.  the compiler will raise a warning.   Suggest the function `main()` signature be changed to: `int main( void )`.   When compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (for gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` (I also use: `-Wconversion -std=c99` )

Comment: when calling `malloc()`: 1) in C, do not cast the returned value.  its' type is `void*` and can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.  2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  3) before exiting the program, pass the returned value to `free()` .  In this simple program it will not make a difference as the OS will cleanup, but in many programs, when the code fails to cleanup after itself, a memory leak will occur.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already are sharing the variable between two threads - it's just that you're not referring to the shared copy in `main`.  To refer to the shared copy, `main` needs to use `args->pingBool`.

However, your code will then not be correct, because it will have a data race - two threads aren't allowed to access a shared variable without using a synchronisation function.  To fix that, you can use a mutex:

```
struct threadArgs {
    pthread_mutex_t lock;
    int pingBool;
};
```

It will need to be initialised:

```
ThreadArgs args = (ThreadArgs)malloc(sizeof(struct threadArgs));
pthread_mutex_init(&args->lock, NULL);
```

`main` should lock the mutex when changing `args->pingBool`:

```
if ( ch == 'q' ) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&args->lock);
    args->pingBool = 0;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&args->lock);
    printf("pingBool now 0\n");
    break;
}
```

and the thread should lock it while reading it:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&args->lock);
while ( args->pingBool == 1 ) {
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&args->lock);
    printf("t1 still going\n");
    sleep(1);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&args->lock);
}
pthread_mutex_unlock(&args->lock);
```

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe I didn't realise I should be using `args->pingBool` in main. And of course, I should be using a mutex.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, solved it myself. The trick was to pass in a pointer to the original variable and access the value of that pointer from `foo()`. Ammended code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h> 
#include <unistd.h>

typedef struct threadArgs * ThreadArgs;

void *foo( void * argStruct );

struct threadArgs{

    int *pingBool; // Now a pointer, not an int
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){

    pthread_t t1; 
    int pingBool = 1;
    int ch;
    ThreadArgs args = (ThreadArgs)malloc(sizeof(struct threadArgs));
    args->pingBool = &pingBool; // pass in a pointer to the variable, rather than the variable itself
    pthread_create(&t1, NULL, foo, args);

    while((ch = getchar()) != EOF ){

        if( ch == 'q' ){
            pingBool = 0;
            printf("pingBool now 0\n");
            break;
        }
    }

    pthread_join(t1, NULL);
    printf("whole program terminating\n");
    return 0;
}

void *foo( void * argStruct ){

    ThreadArgs args = argStruct;
    int * pingBool = args->pingBool;

    while( *pingBool == 1 ){ // access the value of the pointer

        printf("t1 still going\n");
        sleep(1);
    }
    printf("t1 finished\n");
    return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try passing args by reference to `pthread_create()`. It would look like:

```
pthread_create(&t1, NULL, foo, &args);
```